# Properties of the digits of Square Roots of 2

Tags: number-theory, roots, pi

We know a lot of the Properties of the digits of Pi.
However I could'nt find any properties of the digits of Square Root of 2?

Do you know any Articles on this subject?

Comment: We really don't know very much about the digits of $\pi$.

Comment: This question seems too vague.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It is widely conjectured that both $\pi$ and $\sqrt 2$ are [Normal Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) which, loosely speaking, would mean that every finite string of digits would occur somewhere in their decimal expansions.  But nobody has any idea how to prove a thing like that.

Comment: There is something about binary digits, if this is interesting for you at all. Number-of-consecutive zeros or ones depending on the index of the blocks of digits, if I recall right. At the moment I don't have the name of the author...

Comment: I found this one on binary digits: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01722

Comment: $\pi$ has been calculated with a far higher accuracy then $\sqrt{2}$ , but that's it. We do not even know whether a single fixed digit occurs infinite many often in either $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$. We only know that within the calculated digits, $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ exhibit the properties we would expect from a random-digit-generator.

Comment: Concerning normality : Neither $\pi$ , nor $e$ nor any algebraic irrational number has been proven to be normal in any base although it is conjectured that all those numbers are absolutely normal (normal in every base).

Comment: @lulu Actually, "normal" is a stronger property than "every finite digit sequence occurs" , namely : every finite digit sequence occurs in the expected frequency.